# Pie chart colour change on legend drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscharts

I am using google chart api for Pie chart. This works fine but I want to change the colour of pie slice on legend drag and drop . Lets say I have three legends Work , Eat and Commute. So when I drag work legend over work slice it should colour that slice other wise that should be disable or grey. If I drag Work legend on Eat slice it should not colour slice as this is wrong.

Here is the example fiddle.

And Some data code

```
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     9],
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
    ]);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zvxrjxtq/

Comment: there is nothing in your jsfiddle

Comment: @BharatPatidar Just updated pls check.

Comment: The colors don't change in your jsfiddle

Comment: This has nothing to do with highcharts.

Comment: @wergeld any idea how we can do this